# python- how to get the output of the function used in Timer

Tags: python, timer

I want to run a function for 10s then do other stuff. This is my code using Timer

```
from threading import Timer
import time

def timeout():
    b='true'
    return b

a='false'    
t = Timer(10,timeout)
t.start()

while(a=='false'):
    print '1'
    time.sleep(1)
print '2'
```

I know that using Timer I can print something at the end of the timer (print b instead of return b return true after 10s).
What I want to know is : can I get the value returned by timeout() inside "a" to perform my while loop correctly?

Or is there another way to do it with another function ?

Comment: what is `a`,the `while loop`?

Comment: the 'a' in the while loop has to be replaced by 'true' (from timeout()) after 10s, but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Try changing `timeout`'s code to `global a; a = 'true'`. (By the way, why are you using strings instead of ordinary boolean `True` and `False` values?)

Comment: is there a reason you're not using Python's built-in boolean type? (True, False)?

Comment: A simple mistake for the strings instead of booleans

Comment: By the way thank you Kevin, global a works just fine

Comment: global is very rarely the way to go in python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of the function is just dropped by `Timer`, as we can see in the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/threading.py#L1189). A way to go around this, is to pass a mutable argument and mutate it inside the function:

```
def work(container):
    container[0] = True

a = [False]
t = Timer(10, work, args=(a,))
t.start()

while not a[0]:
    print "Waiting, a[0]={0}...".format(a[0])
    time.sleep(1)

print "Done, result: {0}.".format(a[0])
```

Or, use `global`, but that's not the way a gentleman goes.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your solution, I want to be a gentleman ;)

Answer (score 3):

Timer objects wait and execute the callback function in a separate thread. If you want to return a value, you need to set up some kind of inter-thread communication. The easiest way to do this would be to set a global variable and have it modified by the callback function:

```
from threading import Timer
import time

return_val = None

def timeout():

    global return_val
    return_val = True
    return

a = False    
t = Timer(10,timeout)
t.start()
count = 0

while not a:
    print count

    time.sleep(1)
    if return_val:
        break

    count += 1

print 'done'
```

Output:

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9
>   done

I know globals are often frowned upon, but they can be fine if used carefully. My usage here is limited strictly to the case where I am establishing shared memory to be modified by only one thread and precision is not critical.